# Can I configure a default value for an Azure Functions binding expression?

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core, azure-functions

I want to simplify deployment of my Azure Functions v3 project as much as possible.

As an example, take this function, which uses a binding expression to refer to the `DoTheThingSchedule` appsetting:

```c#
[FunctionName("DoTheThing")]
public async Task Run([TimerTrigger("%DoTheThingSchedule%")]TimerInfo timer)
{
    // do the thing
}
```

For local development I can configure a value for `DoTheThingSchedule` in `local.settings.json`, but I haven't found a way to configure a default value in production, which means I'll always have to explicitly configure this setting in Azure.

Does anyone know of a way to work around this?

Comment: Whatever the configuration you are using with local.settings.json should be able to do these entries in the app settings. For more details, please refer to the document.

Comment: Because Azure Function will not upload the local.settings.json file nor the corresponding value when it is deployed, you need to manually enter it on Azure. If you use VS deployment, you can set the value before deployment.

Comment: Hi, If my answer answered your question, can you [mark it as the answer](https://0730bowmanwindow.blob.core.windows.net/work/mark.png) to end this question?:)

Comment: I don't really have a solution, only your suggestion that it's simply not possible. Therefore, I'm waiting a few days to see if any other answers come in.

Comment: @BowmanZhu, marked your answer now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure needs you to add settings in configuration settings in azure. And it will not upload local.settings.json file to azure. But if you are using VS to publish, you can set the settings before publish:

[image]

Comment: We're actually using Terraform to automate creation of our Azure resources, and deploying from a zip, so I'm not publishing directly from VS.

Comment: @Storm-BE If so, you still have to set it manually on azure. If it is not set, it will not work.

Comment: Too bad :) Then what I'm trying to achieve seems not to be possible

Comment: @Storm-BE We can not put string to a const string, the cron must be const. So if you dont set env var, then there is no way...